# how to add token into header from local-storage in angular service file

Tags: node.js, angular6

how to add token into a header from local storage in the angular service file

Here It's my node API which is I called.....

```
{
app.post('/add',auth,(req,res)=>{

    const token = req.header('access_token');
    console.log(req.header);
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "secretkey",{expiresIn:'24h'});

    item.create({
        product:req.body.product,
        desc:req.body.desc,
        price:req.body.price,
        quantity:req.body.quantity,
        seller_id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(decoded._id)

    },(err,item)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.send(err);}
        else{
        res.send(item);}
    });
});
}
```

this is my angular service file

```
create(product_data: any) { 
    debugger

    let headers = new Headers();
    var token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    headers.append('access_token',token);
    return this.httpClient.post("/seller/add", JSON.stringify(product_data))
      .pipe(tap(res=>{
          console.log(res);
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem exists when you try to add the header, i have my code working with something like this:

```
const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        }); return this._http.post(url, body, { headers }).map((data: any) => data.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpHeaders` class is inmutable, so it returns a cloned object in every modify operation (`append()`, `set()`...). So, if you want to instantiate an empty `HttpHeaders` class, then you should reassign the new modified object when doing an `append` operation.

```
create(product_data: any) { 
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    let headers = new Headers();

    headers = headers.append('access_token', token);

    return this.httpClient.post("/seller/add", JSON.stringify(product_data), { headers })
      .pipe(tap(res =>{
          console.log(res);
    }));
}
```

Also, in this situation, you can instantiate the `HttpHeaders` class directly with the headers you want (cleaner approach) like this (I've also made slighlty modifications to your code (`const` instead of var, quotes and formatting):

```
create(product_data: any) { 
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    const headers = new Headers('access_token', token);

    return this.httpClient.post('/seller/add', JSON.stringify(product_data), { headers })
      .pipe(
        tap(res => console.log(res))
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
createAuthrorizationHeader(): HttpHeaders {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    headers = headers.set('access_token', token);
    return headers
  }

insert(product_data: any) {

    let headers = this.createAuthrorizationHeader();
    console.log(headers);
    return this.httpClient.post("/seller/add", product_data, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(tap(res => {
        console.log(res);
      }))
  }
```